# "survived by her partner" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a autobiography online, and in that context , I come across a phrase

> "she was survived by her partner,.....(partner's name)"

what does the author mean to say?

Comment: Can you please show us you have done some research?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say "someone was *survived by* so-and-so", it means that that someone is deceased, and their surviving relatives are so-and-so.

Here, it means "her partner X was still alive when she died."

Comment: Thanks. Just want to double check: it can also be expressed in some various ways, can't it? "She was survived BY her partner X" = "Her partner X survived her" = "She did NOT survive her partner X". Are they all the same?

Comment: @Ray, yes, those all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It means that after her death, her partner is still alive.

Answer (score 2):

If you see:

> He was 43 and is survived by his wife, a son and daughter.

then that means he died while those family members are still alive.